# StackOverFlowError when deserializing an object in android

Tags: android, io

I've been trying to deserialize an object that was created by a normal JDK in an android application, I get a StackOverFlowError whenever I try to do that.

Can I use an object the I serialized using a JDK in a davlik vm? the file size is 4 MB and its stored in the assets folder, the line that generates the error is the following

```
trie = (Trie<String, String>) new ObjectInputStream( ctx.getAssets().open(FILE_NAME)).readObject(); 


02-10 15:27:41.036: E/AndroidRuntime(2019): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-10 15:27:41.036: E/AndroidRuntime(2019): java.lang.StackOverflowError
02-10 15:27:41.036: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):     at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(DataInputStream.java:414)
02-10 15:27:41.036: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):     at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:433)
02-10 15:27:41.036: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewString(ObjectInputStream.java:2171)
02-10 15:27:41.036: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:918)
02-10 15:27:41.036: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2262)
02-10 15:27:41.036: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2217)
02-10 15:27:41.036: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1291)
02-10 15:27:41.036: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:518)
02-10 15:27:41.036: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
02-10 15:27:41.036: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1443)
....
```

Comment: 4 MiB is quite a few for the stack... Did you try to assign more memory to the Java VM?

Comment: @m0skit0 I am running this on a phone directly

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion, why not you use KvmSerializable it is optimized for android dalvik.

Answer (score 0):

Java object serrialisation is not meant as interchange format,  it's  not guarated to work
over boundaries of different JVM versions ( and androids davlik is quite different ) or class signature changes.   If you like to interchange data, stick to some portable format.

One option woudl be xml ( but pretty verbose ), or you can also use  JSON.  There are a lot of tools to provide data binding to or from those formats.

( I also developed one: https://github.com/ko5tik/jsonserializer )

Answer (score 0):

I think its best you break up the file into pieces, since the stack is not capable of handling anything more than 32k.